# Deploy a docker image on Google Cloud Run

Tags: java, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am trying to deploy a Java Socket application that will serve incoming requests on some port over TCP. The image is building fine and the container is running as expected locally.

However when deploying to GCR it throws the following error

```
{
  "textPayload": "terminated: Application failed to start: Failed to create init process: failed to load /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk//bin/java: exec format error",
  "insertId": "631891ef0005eae9ece915df",
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_run_revision",
    "labels": {
      "project_id": "cumulus-0",
      "service_name": "cumulus",
      "revision_name": "cumulus-00001-hib",
      "location": "asia-south1",
      "configuration_name": "cumulus"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2022-09-07T12:43:27.387764458Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "labels": {
    "instanceId": "00c527f6d4880e8a5a96fbdadc4536870f1e55a884c529efc6f860386bb3766d594380d65a657a35adebed119b05e2007cbef26928db216236f1641e97b306"
  },
  "logName": "projects/cumulus-0/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fvarlog%2Fsystem",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2022-09-07T12:43:27.390641080Z"
}
```

Specifically - `terminated: Application failed to start: Failed to create init process: failed to load /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk//bin/java: exec format error`

this comes when the platform in unsupported for the jvm to run. But it is inside a docker container. I dont know whats the matter with this.

Here is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk update && \
    apk add openjdk17-jre=17.0.4.1_p1-r0

ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk

LABEL in.rainycloud.cumulus="hi@shantanubanerjee.com"

COPY build/libs/cumulus*.jar /usr/lib/

CMD ["/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/bin/java", "-jar", "/usr/lib/cumulus-v0.1.jar", "in.rainycloud.cumulus.Main"]

EXPOSE 33333/tcp
```

Comment: You MUST serve HTTP traffic with Cloud Run. You can't serve custom TCP traffic. Use GKE (autopilot or standard) or Compute Engine for that use case.

Comment: You have incorrectly set up Java in the container. I recommend starting with an official Docker Java image and build from that.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the path seems to be fishy.
Why do you have to provide full java bin path. If your build is depending upon some other libraries which requires c,make tools then try with full jdk too.

Also,check this code. It provides start point for your server

```
# java -jar /usr/local/runme/app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

Full code reference: https://mkyong.com/docker/docker-and-java-application-examples/